# Quick question to string handling

Tags: javascript

I’m pretty new to JavaScript, so I hope you could help me.

I have a top navigation menu with text on image buttons. When the text is just one word everything is fine. When it consists of two words I want to cut the string on the space character and put the second word into the second line.

I know I can find the character with the indexof method. But how would I go from there?

Thanks

Comment: can you post your chunk of code?

Comment: This kind of thing really shouldn't be done with Javascript...

Comment: You need to supply some more context here.  How is the menu created?  How is the JavaScript invoked?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `' '` with `'<br>'`.

```
s = s.replace(/ /g, '<br>')
```